# ReactNavigation headerRight button doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

I am using react-navigation 5.x version and I tried to set a right bar button for the header in a stateful component, but that fails. I spent whole day to resolve this issue and I got stuck with this.

If I include the rightHeader directly on the Stack as given below, it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button
} from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

function MainStackScreen() {
      return (
        <MainStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(201, 53, 78)'
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              }
        }}>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{ title: 'Home', headerShown: false }}/>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="Account"
            component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{ title: 'My Profile', headerShown: true, headerBackTitle: 'Back', headerRight: () => (
                <Button
                  onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                  title="Info"
                  color="#fff"
                />
              ) }}/>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="MenuPackages"
            component={MenuPackageScreen}
            options={{ title: 'Menu Packages', headerShown: true, headerBackTitle: 'Back' }}/>
        </MainStack.Navigator>
      )
    }
```

Nothing shows on the header if I try to set rightHeader on the navigationOptions of component.

```
export default class Profile extends Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      )
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>This is a test</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to see the button because it's color is set to `#fff`. Try deleting `color="#fff"`, or changing to another color, and see if it shows up.